# Set up a Django Project with Mamp?

Tags: python, django, mamp

I just downloaded a newer version of MAMP (3.2.1) and i noticed that this Version has Python installed and also seems to handle SQLite Databases.

Shouldn't I be able to manage Django Projects with it?

Where and how would i install it?

I found some Posts in the Web (before my new MAMP release) where People already trying to get MAMP + Django to work with MySQL but those seemed more complicated to me then the usual setup with Virtualenv + SQLite/Postgres.
I'm pretty new to django but starting a project at the time seems quite simple to me.

If Django would work with MAMP together what would be the advantages?
Anyone has already experiences or useful links?

Comment: I can't see the benefit, to be honest. sqlite is already included with Python, and you don't need Apache until you deploy your website to production because you can use the devserver.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK i gues working with MAMP MySQL has the advantage that i can easy import/export Database with php MyAdmin tool. 
Anyway based on tanorix answer here how for me Django worked with MAMP MySQL Database:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
      'NAME': 'projectdb',                   
      'USER': 'root',
      'PASSWORD': 'root',
      'HOST': '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
      'PORT': '8888',
  }
}
```

Then

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't have knowledge about MAMP but I can give you some elements to put Django Database with WAMP, so I think it can be the same manipulation:

First, in MAMP, you need to create a database, call it : projectdb.
Then, at your settings.py, update your variable DATABASES like this:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
      'NAME': 'projectdb',                   # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
      # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
      'USER': 'root',
      'PASSWORD': '',
      'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
      'PORT': '',                   # Set to empty string for default.
  }
}
```

Then, if you are using South, at your shell write this:

```
python manage.py schemamigration <name of your app> --init
python manage.py syncdb # => create your tables at your MAMP
python manage.py migrate
```